# Website Loads Incredibly Slow in IE

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, joomla, pagespeed

When running IE debugbar and monitoring the Network tab the response time for the html is 190 seconds.

*Tried to include screenshots, but not allowed to yet*

Using the developer tools in Chrome response time is 2.2 seconds.

*Tried to include screenshots, but not allowed to yet*

I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing the significantly slower response time. The site uses Joomla that I didn't install or create the template for.

Gzip is on

Caching is set to:
1 month for images
1 week for JS & CSS
1 day for HTML

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does the developer tools in IE say, where is the delay?

Comment: May need some more info here. What version of IE is it? Are there any errors at all in console? Is there a white screen for all of that time or does the page load bit by bit really slowly? We can narrow it down and the nail for you then dude ;)

Comment: It is IE 9. Here's a screenshot of the network tab in Debug Bar: [link](http://prntscr.com/5mst7) Double-clicking on the url in network tab gives more detail here: [link](http://prntscr.com/5mt33) @samuelf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something on the backend...

I've run the site through webpagetest on both IE9/IE8 and Chrome. As you've already noted Chrome runs fine but IE is very slow (it actually times out on WPT)

This indicates that the server is taking a long time to produce the page for IE - is there any server-side user-agent sniffing going on?

Comment: It turns out it was a module that was using mod_feed to pull in a twitter feed. I never figured out why it was loading so slow in IE, I just made a new module that embedded the twitter widget instead effectively circumventing the problem.